# Referencing own object properties

Tags: javascript

Is there any issue doing the following....

```
var myObject = {
    name: "Johnny",
    init: function() {
        $("body").mousemove(this.setStatus);
    },
    setStatus: function(ev) {
        $("body").append("<div>Mouse Move by: " + myObject.name + "</div>");
    }
};

myObject.init();
```

Is this the best way of referencing an object's property when a class is created in this way (i.e. calling myObject.name from the setStatus function)?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're aware that when `this.setStatus` is triggered the context variable `this` will refer to the element that received the event (i.e. your `<body>`) rather than to `myObject`.

However you really shouldn't refer to `myObject` within the object itself - an object should have no knowledge of what it's being called outside of itself.

To resolve that you can pass `this` as an additional parameter to `.mouseMove` thus:

```
$("body").mousemove(this, this.setStatus);
```

and then within your event handler you can retrieve your current object reference via the event's `data` field:

```
setStatus: function(ev) {
    var self = ev.data;
    $("body").append("<div>Mouse Move by: " + self.name + "</div>");
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the object reference itself? Is there a technical reason why you're advising this?

Comment: @JohnnyRambo it's bad OO design.  You could currently do `var tmp = myObject; myObject = null` and your code would break.  The change I've suggested isolates the _internals_ of your implementation from the _external_ references by which your object is known and would allow the code to keep working.

Comment: I figured that but the reason I created the object in this way was because there won't be any other instances of the class, nor will it be set to null. I will still make the change you're suggesting though as its safer. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnnyRambo you're welcome!  FWIW, it's better for code maintainability too.  If you decide to rename `myObject` you'd no longer have to change any of the internal implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine. If `setStatus` isn't used anywhere else, you can move it to an anonymous function and pass it to `mousemove`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `this` is still available. When passing the function to an event handler, `this` will point to the related DOM node.

Since you are using jQuery, you can use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to bind `this` inside the function to something else:

```
$("body").mousemove($.proxy(this.setStatus, this));
```

However, it would be cleaner to make the original `this` available by other means:

```
var myObject = {
    name: "Johnny",
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("body").mousemove(function(ev) {
            self.setStatus.call(this, ev, self);
        });
    },
    setStatus: function(ev, self) {
        $("body").append("<div>Mouse Move by: " + self.name + "</div>");
    }
};
```

Comment: that works, but then breaks the convention that `this` in an event handler refers to the element that received the event.

Answer (score 0):

That way is fine. Another way of doing it would be to just pass an anonymous function to the mousemove:

```
var myObject = {
    name: "Johnny",
    init: function() {
        var thisObject = this;
        $("body").mousemove(function() {
            $("body").append("<div>Mouse Move by: " + thisObject.name + "</div>");
        });
    }
};

myObject.init();
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGkAK/)