# Better design in order to refer to the own object's properties from an object's method

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a 'yesno' input radio. When user clicks *yes*, a yesDiv is shown, and when user clicks *no*, noDiv is shown.

In order to implement that I created the object *myObject*.

```
var myObject= {
        init: function(config){
            this.config=config;
            this.config.InputRadio.bind('click',this.config,this.switchDiv);
        },
        switchDiv: function(ev){
                    self=ev.data;
            if ($(this).val()==1){
                self.divYes.hide();
                self.divNo.show();
            }else{
                self.divYes.show();
                self.divNo.hide();
            }
        }
}

myObject.init({
        InputRadio:$("input[name=yesno]"),
        divYes:$("#yesDiv"),
        divNo:$("#noDiv")
});
```

This works, I know that I can't use *this* to refer to the object's properties inside the method 'switchDiv' because of the scope of 'this' inside a function. I found the solution of sending *this.config* as a parameter and then using *self=ev.data*,  in a related question ( [Referencing own object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339019/javascript-referencing-own-object-properties).)

But now my question is: Isn't a little strange the fact that whenever I want to access to an object's own properties from a method of that object, I have to pass them as a parameter in the method?  Isn't there a better way to declare the objects to avoid that?

Comment: When `switchDiv` is is called, '`this`' is the radio button.  So it cannot simultaneously be `myObject`.  You take advantage of it being the radio button, by calling `$(this).val()`.  There's no way it can be both the radio button and `myObject`.

Comment: Is there any reason that this has to be in a particular object? with a public API like this?  Do you keep `myObject` around after construction?  Do you call its public `init` and `switchDiv` methods or address its public `config` property again?  Perhaps the code should be buried in an anonymous closure that maintains state but offers no public interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the public API of your object, I think you're best off just not creating such an object at all.  Keep all the state in a hidden scope, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/xbyBh/)

```
var createYesNoToggler = function(radioName, yesId, noId) {
    var divYes = $("#" + yesId), divNo = $("#" + noId),
        radios = $("input[name=" + radioName + "]");
    radios.click(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            divYes.show();
            divNo.hide();
        } else {
            divYes.hide();
            divNo.show();
        }
    });
};

createYesNoToggler("yesno", "yesDiv", "noDiv");
```

Or, if you only need the one, then don't even make the function public:

```
(function(radioName, yesId, noId) {
    var divYes = $("#" + yesId), divNo = $("#" + noId),
        radios = $("input[name=" + radioName + "]");
    radios.click(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            divYes.show();
            divNo.hide();
        } else {
            divYes.hide();
            divNo.show();
        }
    });
}("yesno", "yesDiv", "noDiv"));
```

(but that latter might be done in somewhat simpler ways if you don't need more than one.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that `this` refers to `myObject` when you call `switchDiv`, my recommendation is to change your `init` function a bit. I've also updated your `switchDiv` function to reflect this. You still need to reassign `this`, but only in the `init` function

```
var myObject= {
        init: function(config){
            var _this = this;
            this.config=config;
            this.config.InputRadio.on('change',function(){
                _this.switchDiv(); // now "this" will refer to myObject, not the input
            });
        },
        switchDiv: function(){
            if (this.config.InputRadio.filter(":checked").val() === '1'){
                this.config.divYes.hide();
                this.config.divNo.show();
            }else{
                this.config.divYes.show();
                this.config.divNo.hide();
            }
        }
};
```

By wrapping your call to `switchDiv` within an anonymous function, you can better maintain the context of `this`.

Here's a demo showing it in action:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/VSdAL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/VSdAL/)

On a related note, it is not recommended to use `self` when assigning `this` to a variable for use within callbacks or other functions. `self`, by default, is a shortcut for `window.self`, which is a global variable referring to the current window. You don't want to reassign it on the chance that you muck up some other code using `self`

Comment: This is missing the point that the object's function has been bound to the event handler for the radio button.  When it's triggered, `this` is now the radio button.

Comment: my mistake; I've edited my answer to better address the question at hand

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 1.5 (not supported by all browsers) has a method [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the `this` value:

```
this.config.InputRadio.bind('click', this.switchDiv.bind(this));
```

Now `this` will always refer to `myObject` when the bound `switchDiv` is called and you can use `this.config` directly instead of passing event data.